# Get Google search query term

Tags: php, laravel, analytics, google-search

We have an analytics requirement where we need to display keyword searches in google which resulted in users coming to our site.

We store each request hitlog and process it. This hitlog stores request header information, which helps in analyzing details like device user used, OS, browser, etc.

To get search query term user searched on google, we tried to extract details from referer in the request header. But we realize that search terms are absent in the referer.

Following is the code snippet:

```
// Parse Query
$parsed_query = urldecode(parse_url($request->header('referer', null);, PHP_URL_QUERY));
if (str_contains($parsed_query, "q=")) {
    preg_match('~q=(.*?)&~', $parsed_query, $query);
    if (!empty($query)) {
        $query = $query[1];
        if (filter_var($query, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            $parsed_path = urldecode(parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_PATH));
            if (str_contains($parsed_path, 'url') && $source == 'google') {
                $query = '';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work.

There are few who are able to do that like Awstats, Wordpress, Nowfloats, etc.

So how can these able to retrieve search query term, the user searched in google?

NOTE: We are using laravel php framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should [check this out](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/unlock-keyword-not-provided/):

> If a user is logged into a Google product (such as Gmail or any Google
>   Account) when searching, their search is conducted over SSL. As such,
>   the referral data relating to that search is hidden.
>
> Referral data includes some useful information such as the keywords
>   used to perform that search. Google can still see this information,
>   but website owners – and Analytics account holders – can’t access it.

If you want to retrieve search query term, you should install [google webmaster](https://www.google.com/webmasters) and [google analytics](https://analytics.google.com/) to your website.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We have already installed google analytics on the website. But how can I display search query results on our dashboard using it?

Comment: you can check under `Acquisition > Search Console > Queries` in google analytics, and should link to search console if you didn't (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1120006?hl=en)